# Проверить ключ на соответствие массиву ключей через PHP

Tags: php

В скрипт извне приходит строка, например "crab"
Также имеется массив стоп слов

```
$stopwords = ["auto", "scrabing", "road"]
```

Как проверить пришедшую строку на соответствие ключам массива $stopwords средствами PHP ?
Например в случае строки "crab" должно быть найдено соответствие со значением элемента массива "s**crab**ing"

Есть вариант сделать это без регулярных выражений? Нужен максимально быстрый и наименее ресурсоёмкий для процессора вариант.

Answer (score 0):

По скорости не тестировал, но вариант без регулярок:

```
$need = 'crab';
$stopwords = ["auto", "scrabing", "road"];

$result = array_filter($stopwords, function($item) use($need) {
    return (strpos($item, $need) !== false);
});

if ($result) {
    echo "Найдено совпадение подстроки '$need' : ". join(', ', $result);
}
```

**UPD:** Если вам не нужно получение элемента массива, с которым совпала подстрока, то можно записать так:

```
$need = 'crab';
$stopwords = ['auto', 'scrabing', 'road'];

echo strpos(join(', ', $stopwords), $need) !== false ? 'Найдено совпадение!' : '';
```